# Working with local storage in the browser: removing item

Tags: javascript

I have found this very simple to do list. The inputs get stored as it should in the local storage, but I have problems with the "removing item" section in JS. The items are removed from the html but not from the local storage. So when it is refreshed the items I thought I removed are still there and I do not understand why. Also I do not understand `firstElementChild` and why it is there.

```js
/*variables */
const addForm = document.querySelector('.add');
const list = document.querySelector('.todos');
// salvato gli items dal local storage in una variabile
let storedItems = localStorage.getItem('tasks');

const generateTemplate = todo => {
    const html = `
    <li>
        <span>${todo}</span>
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
    </li>`
    
    list.innerHTML += html;
}

if (!storedItems) {
    storedItems = [];
} else {
    storedItems = JSON.parse(storedItems);
    storedItems.forEach(item => {
        generateTemplate(item);
    });
}

addForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    const todo = addForm.add.value.trim();
    e.preventDefault();
    if (todo.length) {
        generateTemplate(todo); 
        storedItems.push(todo);
        localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(storedItems))
        addForm.reset();
        console.log(`${todo} has been added to html list`)
        console.log(`Local storage now contains ${storedItems}`)
    }
});

/*Removing item*/

list.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log(e.target);
    if (e.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
        let removedItem = e.target.parentElement.firstElementChild.innerText;
        console.log(`${removedItem} has been removed from the html list`);
        console.log(storedItems)
        const newArr = storedItems.filter(item => item !== removedItem)
        console.log(newArr)
        storedItems = newArr
        console.log(`Local storage now contains ${storedItems} `)
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Todolist</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" class="add">
        <h1>To do list</h1>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="add" placeholder="Enter name here">
   <ul class="todos"></ul>
    </form>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing items from local array but not setting updated array to local storage. Just add

```
window.localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(storedItems))
```

after

```
storedItems = newArr
```

in your code. @TheBritishAreComing approach will work when you want to remove complete list instead of individual task

Comment: Thank you for that, I think I have deleted that part..
How about  `firstElementChild`? what does that line mean

Comment: Actually you need to target text to delete from local Storage as well as UI and for deleting an element you click on delete icon. By using DOM element tree you are navigating to the sibling element with the help of parent. So your parent's first child `firstElementChild` is your sibling (text of task). Hopefully you get something from this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

all this code is doing is manipulating the storedItems array, but it's not touching local storage.

```
if (e.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
        let removedItem = e.target.parentElement.firstElementChild.innerText;
        console.log(`${removedItem} has been removed from the html list`);
        console.log(storedItems)
        const newArr = storedItems.filter(item => item !== removedItem)
        console.log(newArr)
        storedItems = newArr
        console.log(`Local storage now contains ${storedItems} `)
    }
```

You need to use, before you update your global array
`localStorage.removeItem(removedItem);`

Docs for localStorage.removeItem can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem)